# Fall Back Google CDN in JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript, cdn, google

In [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) it Grab Google CDN's jQuery with this JS code

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

I tried to transpose it to WP with this PHP code

```
function sbi_cdn_jquery()
{
    global $wp_scripts;

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    echo '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' . $wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver . '/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    echo '<script>window.jQuery || document.write(\'<script src="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"<\/script>\')</script>';
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sbi_cdn_jquery' );
```

But this does not work !

Is this possible to fallBack Google CDN in JavaScript with WP ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/sgarbesi/fallback.js It's a library that I wrote that allows you to add as many fallback CDN's as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Scripts don't get **printed** at the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook, but rather at the `wp_print_scripts` hook. That said: **don't echo/print scripts, period**. Instead, **enqueue** them properly.

**Caveat**: This method is Plugin territory, and should not be included as Theme code in a publicly distributed Theme.

You *deregister* jQuery, but the step you're missing is *registering* and *enqueueing* your own version:

```
<?php
function sbi_cdn_jquery() {
    // Deregister core-bundled jQuery
    // This is dangerous! Understand the
    // potential consequences before doing this!
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    // Register custom jQuery version
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' );

    // Enqueue cusotm jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sbi_cdn_jquery' );
?>
```

Refer to the Codex entry for [**`wp_register_script()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [**`wp_enqueue_script()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) regarding arguments for these functions.

Comment: Excellent answer, with only one question. Wouldn't it be better to add `if ( ! is_admin() )` before you deregister jQuery? I've always assumed it was unwise to swap in your version of jQuery for the admin area as it could potentially cause unwanted issues.

Comment: Absolutely. My answer isn't comprehensive regarding all best practices with respect to enqueueing scripts - primarily because the premise of the question itself goes against best practice.

Comment: Thank for your answer.
But if Google CDN does not respond, how can i load local WP Jquery (fall back to local if offline) ?

Comment: "*But if Google CDN does not respond*" - that's but one of the myriad reasons **not to deregister core-bundled scripts** in the first place.

Comment: @ChipBennett He is trying to have a fallback mechanism just like we have in HTML5 Boilerplate. Having a fallback is the best way among any other way.

Comment: "*Having a fallback is the best way among any other way.*" - No. In WordPress, **using the core-bundled version** is the "best way among any other way."

Comment: @Chip Bennett Why _using the core-bundled version is the "best way among any other way."_  ? In my code I load WP JQuery version => `$wp_scripts->registered['jquery']->ver` I want to test it on client side by checking if jQuery has been defined

Comment: "*Why using the core-bundled version is the "best way among any other way." ?*" - Really, that's outside the scope of this question, and has been covered in other `wp_enqueue_script()` questions here on WPSE.

Comment: @ChipBennett I know the concern raised on using the core bundled version when issues came up when some premium themes were replacing it, but I hope you know what bleeding edge is. I am not talking about non-techie consumers here, but developers. So Yes! Having a fallback is the best way. I know what runs in my site. When you talk about normal audience, don't assume that people like me are included.

Comment: @Ashfame: I assume anyone advanced enough to know the risks and caveats with this approach would also be advanced enough not to need to ask a basic question about script enqueueing.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function to register and enqueue the various scripts my theme uses:

```
function cosmos_enqueue_scripts() {

// Load jquery from Google CDN (protocol relative) with local fallback when not available
if ( false === ( $url = get_transient('jquery_url') ) ) {

    // Check if Google CDN is working
    $url = ( is_ssl() ? 'https:' : 'http:' ) . '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
    $resp = wp_remote_head($url);

    // Load local jquery if Google down
    if ( is_wp_error($resp) || 200 != $resp['response']['code'] ) {

        $url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js';
    }

    // Cache the result for 5 minutes to save bandwidth
    set_transient('jquery_url', $url, 60*5);
}

// Deregister Wordpress' jquery and register theme's copy in the footer
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
wp_register_script('jquery', $url, array(), null, true);

// Load other theme scripts here
wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js', array(        ), null, false);
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js'      , array('jquery'), null, true );
wp_enqueue_script('main'     , get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js'                      , array('jquery'), null, true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cosmos_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: This will slow things down a bit and moreover only checks when the PHP actually ran and not everytime when the cached pages are served. Best is to do it on client side by checking if jQuery has been defined just after loading it.

Comment: Good point about caching. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Posted the same answer on [jquery stopped working after deregistering wordpress stock version](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66865/jquery-stopped-working-after-deregistering-wordpress-stock-version/66880#66880), but adding here for reference:

If you're stuck on using a Google hosted version of jQuery, there are two plugins that come to mind:

- [Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/)
- [WP jQuery Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-jquery-plus/)

It's better to just use the core if you're not 100% comfortable with JavaScript debugging (if anything pops up as it did) and do not control the environment completely.